# How to get bazel/gazelle go_repository imports past go vet

Tags: go, bazel, bazel-gazelle, gazelle

I'm using bazel/gazelle to pull in some external git repositories.
For example:

```
go_repository(
    name = "com_github_pkg_errors",
    importpath = "github.com/pkg/errors",
    sum = "h1:iURUrRGxPUNPdy5/HRSm+Yj6okJ6UtLINN0Q9M4+h3I=",
    version = "v0.8.1",
)
```

My go file would just import `github.com/pkg/errors` like normal.
Problem comes when I run `go vet` on my file. It would complain that no such package exists under GOROOT or GOPATH. This repo is located in my bazel cache. `~/.cache/bazel/.../external/com_github_pkg_errors`

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to specify the dependency in `go.mod`

```
require (
    github.com/pkg/errors v0.8.1
)
```

2. In the `BUILD.bazel` file of your project, specify `go_library` with `dep`

```
go_library(
    name = "project_lib",
    srcs = [],
    importpath = "github.com/pkg/errors",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "@com_github_pkg_errors",
    ],
)
```